# Why is "My boss is going on holiday tomorrow" better than "My boss will go on holiday tomorrow"?

Tags: future-tense

I need help about the use of the future tense. The sentence was like this:

> My boss--------on holiday tomorrow.

I have chosen ''will go'' but the key was "is going".
Please explain it.

I think if there were the present progressive or construction "be going to" there should be "is going to" but there was not "to".

Comment: Either one is correct. The present progressive tense can indicate near future actions when used with a time word like "tomorrow".

Answer (score 1):

"Is going to" has a connotation of intention as well as futurity (and "is going" is often used when you might expect "is going to go"). "Will" does not.

So, "My boss is going on holiday tomorrow", has the sense that this is my boss's plan.

"My boss will go on holiday tomorrow" does not have this sense: it does not exclude it, but it does not suggest it. Since the first sentence is also available, if a native speaker used this, it might imply that it was not the boss's plan - perhaps he was told that tomorrow was the only time he may take his holiday.

Answer (score 0):

"Will" is used like if something is definitely do something. "Is going to" is used like something will do something with it's own. In this case, My boss is on holiday by themselves. So, "Is going to" is better.